# Component of select box not working in view format in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, select, components

I have the logic error in laravel in the view component. I have created one select box and for its value, I'm getting it from a database table. While viewing only the last value of the table is getting displayed when I compiled the code.
Here I have attached my component file and view file.

My view file: **newuphist.blade.php**

```
@if(isset($data))
<div class="field_wrapper">

@component('compnew')
    @slot('select')
       select

         @foreach($data as $item)

           @slot('opt')
          {{$item->diseaseName}}
         @endslot
      @endforeach

    @endslot

    @slot('txtbx')
        MM
     @endslot
 @endcomponent

@endif
```

and my component file: **compnew.blade.php**

```
<select name="{{ $select }}"  value="{{ $select }}" >
<option name="{{$opt}}" value="{{$opt}}">{{$opt}}</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="{{$txtbx}}" value="{{$txtbx}}">
```

Someone, please help me to find out how can I display all values in the select box.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After know about the Laravel view basics, I have found the answer.

```
@if(isset($data))
<div class="field_wrapper">

@component('compnew',['select'=>'select','txtbx'=>'MM'])
         @slot('opt')
         @foreach($data as $item)
          <option value="{{$item->diseaseName}}">
            {{$item->diseaseName}}
          </option>
         @endforeach
         @endslot
@endcomponent
@endif
```

My component file:

```
<select name="{{!empty($select) ? $select : '' }}"  value="{{!empty($select) ? $select : '' }}" >
     {{!empty($opt) ? $opt : '' }}

</select>
<input type="text" name="{{!empty($txtbx) ? $txtbx : '' }}" value="{{!empty($txtbx) ? $txtbx : '' }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should Pass the component in foreach and then you will try it.

```
@if(isset($data))
  <div class="field_wrapper">

     @foreach($data as $item)
           @component('compnew')
                @slot('select')
                     select
                @slot('opt')
                     {{$item->diseaseName}}
                @endslot
                @endslot
                @slot('txtbx')
                     MM
                @endslot
           @endcomponent
     @endforeach                       
@endif
```

Comment: It Doesn't add a values into the select box.Instead of this it creates certain number of select boxes.Thanks for your Answer.